# Subtract one from unsigned long long variable in atomic operation in CUDA kernel

Tags: cuda, atomic

I have an `unsigned long long count` that requires an atomic decrement inside of a CUDA kernel. How do I do this in a proper way?

```
atomicAdd(&count, -1); // Impossible as second argument is also required to be `unsigned long long`.
atomicSub(&count, 1); // Impossible, because `unsigned long long` is not supported.
```

Comment: Twos-complement integers are being used, so subtraction of 1 is equivalent to addition of `0xffffffffffffffffULL` for an `unsigned long long int` argument.

Comment: @njuffa. Thanks, did not know that, that works indeed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The integer types on all platforms supported by CUDA use twos-complement representation. This means that subtracting a number *n* from a counter *n* is the same as adding the two's complement of *n* to *c*. Integer types of the same size can easily be typecast between signed and unsigned representations. Therefore, instead of adding the two's complement as 1 as `0xffffffffffffffffULL`, which looks a bit like a magic constant, we can use the more readable `(unsigned long long int)(-1LL)`.

Below is a short CUDA program that initializes an `unsigned long long int` counter to a non-zero starting value and then decrements if once per thread in the launched kernel. Note that error checking has been eliminated for brevity and clarity of exposition, which is not something one would want to do in actual code.

```cuda
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define BLOCK_COUNT  (2)
#define THREAD_COUNT (256)

__global__ void kernel (unsigned long long int *counter)
{
    atomicAdd (counter, (unsigned long long int)(-1LL));
}

int main (void)
{
    unsigned long long int counter;
    unsigned long long int *counter_d = 0;
    cudaMalloc ((void**)&counter_d, sizeof (*counter_d));
    cudaMemset (counter_d, 0x01, sizeof (*counter_d));
    cudaMemcpy (&counter, counter_d, sizeof counter, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    printf ("counter before kernel = %llu\n", counter);
    printf ("decrement counter with %lld threads\n", BLOCK_COUNT * THREAD_COUNT);
    kernel<<<BLOCK_COUNT, THREAD_COUNT>>>(counter_d);
    cudaMemcpy (&counter, counter_d, sizeof counter, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    printf ("counter after kernel  = %llu\n", counter);
    cudaFree (counter_d);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize ();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The output of this program should look like this:

```
counter before kernel = 72340172838076673
decrement counter with 512 threads
counter after kernel  = 72340172838076161
```